# SQL Server: Getting opposite entry to a row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This question is a bit hard to explain.

Every appraisal has an opposite appraisal. An employee appraises their educator and the educator appraises the employee. Thus, we have 2 appraisal rows for each plan element, which contains the timeframe.

I want to create an SQL statement which returns appraisals which are opposite to the one that is given to the statement as a parameter.

This is how far I've gotten and I'm stuck. The statement I've made doesn't even make sense.

```
DECLARE @Appraisal_ID_Param INTEGER
SET @Appraisal_ID_Param = ?

SELECT *
FROM [Appraisal]
RIGHT JOIN [Plan]
ON 
    [Plan].[Plan_ID] = [Appraisal].[Plan_ID] AND
    [Appraisal].[Appraisal_ID] != @Appraisal_ID_Param;
```

Here's a part of my database model:

[image: database model]

Basically, I need to return those appraisals that are not `@Appraisal_ID_Param` but share the same `Plan_ID`.

I really hope that I was clear enough because I've been stuck on this issue for quite a while and it's rather confusing.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must join `Appraisal` for twice:

```
DECLARE @Appraisal_ID_Param INTEGER
SET @Appraisal_ID_Param = ?

SELECT DISTINCT A_TO.*
FROM [Appraisal] A_FROM
RIGHT JOIN [Appraisal] A_TO
ON 
    [A_FROM].[Plan_ID] = [A_TO].[Plan_ID] AND
    [A_TO].[Appraisal_ID] != @Appraisal_ID_Param
WHERE
    [A_FROM].[Appraisal_ID] = @Appraisal_ID_Param
```

Comment: I've tried your statement and it works flawlessly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Apparently one appraisal has one plan on your database, which means you could initially find the `ID` of that plan, based on the `AppraisalId` you have as a parameter and then select only those appraisals that have the same `PlanId` but `AppraisalID` different from the parameter:

```
DECLARE @Appraisal_ID_Param INTEGER
SET @Appraisal_ID_Param = ?

DECLARE @PlanId INTEGER = (SELECT [Plan_ID] FROM Appraisal WHERE [Appraisal_ID] = @Appraisal_ID_Param)

SELECT * -- all information
FROM 
          [Appraisal] appr 
     JOIN [Plan] p ON  p.[Plan_ID] = appr.[Plan_ID]
WHERE 
          p.[Plan_ID] = @PlanId 
      AND appr.[Appraisal_ID] <> @Appraisal_ID_Param
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this?

```
DECLARE @Appraisal_ID_Param INTEGER
SET @Appraisal_ID_Param = ?

SELECT top 1 *
FROM Appraisal 
where 
    plan_id = (select plan_id 
               from Appraisal 
               where Appraisal_ID = @Appraisal_ID_Param
               ) 
    and Appraisal_ID <> @Appraisal_ID_Param
```